# Мы уверены и мы наслышаны - есть разница?

Tags: грамматика

1) Мы столько наслышались о вас. Мы *наслышаны* о ваших подвигах.

Есть зависимое слово, пишется одна буква Н. Это причастие или прилагательное?

2) Так мы уверилась в надежности машины. Теперь мы *уверены*  в ее надежности.

Есть зависимое слово, пишется одна буква Н. Это причастие или прилагательное?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из комментария ***Jasmin*** в этой теме:

> И если считать "уверены" прилагательным, тогда и "наслышаны" тоже
>   прилагательное? Но оно как-то мало похоже на прилагательное.

Как раз "наслышаны"-то при любом контексте будет прилагательным. Кратким прилагательным, не имеющим полной формы.

Есть оно и у Зализняка:

> наслышан п 1а, *пф нет*

А вот страдательное причастие от глагола ***наслышаться*** не образуется (по Зализняку).

Answer (score 1):

§ 102. Краткие формы прилагательных на -нный пишутся с одним н, если эти прилагательные требуют зависимых слов и не имеют формы сравнительной степени. Примеры: привязанный к кому-либо 'испытывающий привязанность' — Она к нему очень привязана; исполненный чего-либо 'полный, проникнутый' — Душа исполнена печали; послышанный о чём-либо 'хорошо осведомленный' — **Мы наслышаны о его проделках. (См. в приведенных примерах зависимые слова: к нему, печали, о его проделках.)**

[См.: Академический справочник](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=6#pp6)

Comment: Я знаю, что краткие прилагательные в этом случае пишутся с одной Н, но почему это именно прилагательные, по каким признакам? По значению они - получившие информацию, а это причастие. И вообще, как это правило связано с грамматикой, как оно объясняется? Эти слова кажутся особенными - нечто среднее между прилагательным и причастием.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо все ответившим, я еще подумала над вопросом и сделала (для себя) такой вывод.

Все эти формы (начитанный, наслышанный, уверенный) являются прилагательными, так как соотносятся с глаголами *начитаться, наслышаться, увериться*, а это возвратные и поэтому **непереходные** глаголы. (Страдательные причастия прошедшего времени образуются от переходных глаголов, это формальный признак).

Да и по смыслу у этих форм нет чёткого значения признака как результата конкретного законченного действия, например: начитаться – много читать, прочитать много книг, наслышаться – много раз слышать.

В то же время глаголы эти особенные, некоторые могут употребляться и без частицы СЯ (уверить – увериться), значения у них – это нечто среднее меду общим отношением к действию и результатом действия.

Поэтому они считаются прилагательными, но к ним применяют правила написания для причастий (одна буква Н), если они имеют **зависимые слова**, которые сближают их с причастиями.